# Getting file diff with Github API

Tags: api, github

net project for which I need to detect and parse changes made to a specific single text file in a  repository between different pull requests.

I've been successfully able to access the pull requests and the commits using the Github API but I don't know how to retrieve the lines that changed in the last commit?

Is this possible using the API? What would be the best approach? 
If not should I try to read the last two file versions and implement a differ algorithm locally?
Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A pull request contains a `diff_url` entry like

```
"diff_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1347.diff"
```

You can do this for any commit. For example, to get the diff of commit  7fd1a60b01f91b3 on octocat's Hello-World it's https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/commit/7fd1a60b01f91b314f59955a4e4d4e80d8edf11d.diff.

This also works for branches. Here's master on octocat's Hello-World. https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/commit/master.diff.

The general form is:

```
https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>/commit/<commit>.diff
```

Comment: For those who find this answer: I want to add that you need to specify the `"Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.diff"` header (`patch` also works). Source: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/Get-pull-request-diff-from-API/td-p/19317

Comment: Only works for public repositories. Does not support authentication.

Comment: I just had to pass the header (as @Shersh mentioned). Didn't have to append the `.diff`. I'm also hitting a /commits endpoint and not /commit. So maybe things have changed since 2016.

Comment: I was able to get the diff string in node using the @oktokit/core package, and from a private repo, like this:

 const oktokit = new Octokit({
    auth: 'optionalToken',
  });
oktokit.request(
    'GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits',
    {
      owner: 'repoOwner',
      repo: 'repoTitle',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/vnd.github.diff',
      },
    }
  )

Latest github docs on the vnd header type: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/media-types?apiVersion=2022-11-28#diff

Answer (score 3):

For private repositories:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.diff" https://<personal access token>:x-oauth-basic@api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo>/pulls/<pull request>
```

Also works with the normal cURL `-u` parameter.

See: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#get-a-pull-request

Answer (score 1):

The crux is in the requested media type. You can pass the `Accept` header with value

> `application/vnd.github.diff`

see [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#custom-media-types-for-pull-requests). For full reference, a GET request with the above and Authorization header to `https://api.github.com/repos/{orgName}/{repoName}/pulls/{prId}` does the trick.